# Some questions regarding Xbox Live Service

Tags: xbox-live-arcade, xbox-network, xbox-360

I recently bought Xbox 360 with Kinect in US and brought it to India and I haven't yet created a Xbox Live account. I have some questions regarding how Xbox Live will work with regards to the different countries I purchased and am using my Xbox in.

1. Since my Xbox was bought in US do I need to create Xbox Live account with my country as the US? Or do I create an account with my country as India? India has the Xbox Live Arcade but I am not sure if the content is the same. Pros and cons of both approaches?
2. Will games bought in India work? Or do I need to buy them from the US?
3. Any other issues that I might face? Or any suggestions I should follow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your X-Box account for any country, however you can only change countries once every 12 months. This can be done via the X-Box live website. You have to however copy all your downloaded content to a backup USB since you can't re-download these. Also the country on your Live account and the X-Box account must match, otherwise it will create some havoc. To access the change your region options on X-Box live look for the following on your account:

[image]

Unfortunately I am getting the following screen since I recently did this, however you will get the option to choose a country:

[image]

Gamercards can only redeemed for the country they are bought for, as they are linked to the Live store for each country.

The only reason I can imagine your games won't work bought in India, is if they are not PAL/NTSC compatible depending on what you use. South Africans for a long time bought Australian and UK X-Boxes and bought games locally and they worked fine.

Comment: i finally checked it out today and your info is only partly true. You can only change to one of the following countries: Rusia, Poland, Brazil, Hungary, greece, Tsjechië, South Africa, Colombia en Chili. (i translate dthese countries from dutch hope i spelled it right.) So you cant change it to the uk (my case) or to india (In his case if he makes a usa account.)

Comment: @Andy. It's a fairly new service, and I know they said they will be adding more countries. As with everything XBox related it will just be a case of time. I couldn't confirm countries myself since I already did a switch from a UK account.

Comment: Well, i hope my attempted translations are any help to people trying to decide. Still, after all these years it is a step in the right direction. but forfeiting the ability to redownload all the things i bought is a steep price. I'd say thinking carefully about your country for xboxlive is important since i doubt they will remove that consequence.

Comment: @Andy. Backing it up to a USB devices solves the problem. If you ever need to replace the XBox completely, just copy it from the USB. I recently switched from the original XBox to the new Slim and it worked fine. Incidentally it was around the same time I realised I could change countries.

Answer (score 1):

Be carefull, if you register your xboxlive in the usa you need to buy your gold cards in the usa. gold cards from india will not work.

luckly america is a big country so you could buy your gold cards on ebay, but be aware that me moving from Belgium to the UK means i have to travel back to belgium or let someone buy an xboxlive card in belgium.

On the same note, i need a belgian bank card to buy anything for xboxlive, i can't use a UK one since thats not my home country.

At this time it is only possible to change to certain countries, and usa, uk nor India are some of them.

I know that certain content is Region limited, however, they are checking the country you are in with ip as well, cause i know a french guy that had to use a proxy to avoid that.

Last warning about games on demand on xbox live, i am not sure how india is in official languages and so, but i downloaded CoC: WaW from xbox live, with an english description and interface, however, once downloaded, the game was in french. be carefull about it all

Comment: I have just bought the Xbox so i really don't have any achievements to worry about. So you are saying that i can create a account here in India , I can use it with my US bought XBox?

Comment: yes, the country you buy the xbox i is unrelated to the country of your live account. You will need an email to create an xboxlive account and it will default it to the country of email when signing up but this can be changed before the signup is complete.

Comment: Actually your wrong. Your allowed to change your country on your Xbox Live account once every 12 months and keep all your content etc, however you can't re-download content from another region once you've done the change. I just did this recently when they finally launched XBLA in South Africa, to change from a UK account. You can do this through the Xbox live website on your account. You keep all gamer points you've gained etc.

Comment: @Diago: That would be great news. and relativly new. i will check on this as soon as i can.